# Autohotkey - Keyboard Input to Only One Program

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to make it so that I can read and scroll through my Adobe Reader using the mouse, but when I start typing, I want it to go to my OneNote to take notes while I'm reading. I can set OneNote to always be on top through the software itself, so making it the active window is not a mandatory requirement, but it would work too when I have it always on top. It would be nice though if I could keep the other windows I am using the active ones but the keyboard inputs going to OneNote.

I have tried a few different things, but I am definitely no expert and missing something(s).

**Attempt 1** (the problem with this one is, the first key I press is registered in the open window, creating havoc with my reader - rather than going to OneNote):

```
#InstallKeybdHook
SetTimer, AnyKeyPressed, 100

AnyKeyPressed:
    if( A_TimeIdlePhysical < 100 ){
    WinActivate, ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
    }
```

**Attempt 2** (this works for bringing up OneNote and not registering the key in the open window, but I can't actually type anything inside of OneNote):

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, AnyKeyPressed, 100

AnyKeyPressed:
 #IfWinActive ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
 {
    SendInput % "{sc" Format("{:03X}", sc) "}"
 }

#IfWinNotActive ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
{
    AnyEndKeys =
    ( LTrim Join
       {LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}
       {LShift}{RShift}{LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}
       {F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}
       {Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}
       {Insert}{Delete}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}
       {Space}{Tab}{Enter}{Escape}{Backspace}
       {CapsLock}{NumLock}{ScrollLock}
       {PrintScreen}{Pause}
       {Numpad0}{Numpad1}{Numpad2}{Numpad3}{Numpad4}
       {Numpad5}{Numpad6}{Numpad7}{Numpad8}{Numpad9}
       {NumpadIns}{NumpadEnd}{NumpadDown}{NumpadPgDn}{NumpadLeft}
       {NumpadClear}{NumpadRight}{NumpadHome}{NumpadUp}{NumpadPgUp}
       {NumpadDot}{NumpadDel}
       {NumpadDiv}{NumpadMult}{NumpadSub}{NumpadAdd}{NumpadEnter}
    )

    Input AnyKey, L1, %AnyEndKeys%
    WinActivate, ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
}
```

**Attempt 3** (this one works great, but I can't get the escape keys to work properly - I can't use the backspace for example. Also, when I press enter, it puts the new line at the top and not where the cursor left off):

```
#InstallKeybdHook
Loop {
    Input,anykey,L1,{LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{Capslock}{Numlock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
    ControlSend, OneNote::DocumentCanvas1, %anykey%, ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
}
```

I know there is probably a solution in the combination of these, and/or something simple I just need to add, but my brain is fried from school and a newborn, I just want to be able to write notes while I am reading without having to keep switching windows back and forth constantly.

Thanks so much for the help, I can't afford to spend any more time falling behind!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a combination of your code plus user3419297's code below.

I don't know why OneNote misbehaves and doesn't keep the 'cursor' at the end as expected. You can slightly work around it by sending {End} but you can't really edit right unless you just want a running log.

Capturing all keystrokes and sending them to another window is not ideal as you are finding... I'm not sure exactly what your navigation methods are for dealing with Acrobat but I would have been definitely tempted to do this the other way around.

In other words, I doubt I would try and send all keystrokes to OneNote while navigating in Acrobat... instead I would do all the editing in OneNote while sending certain keystrokes/mouse clicks etc. to Acrobat in order to navigate the pdf--if you have limited navigational interaction with Acrobat that seems like it would be a lot easier.

Test Code

```
Loop {
    If thisID:=WinActive(myWinTitle:="ahk_exe Acrobat.exe") {
        
        keys = *1,*2,*3,*4,*5,*6,*7,*8,*9,*0,*a,*b,*c,*d,*e,*f,*g,*h,*i,*j,*k,*l,*m,*n,*o,*p,*q,*r,*s,*t,*u,*v,*w,*x,*y,*z,*Space,*Enter,*Tab,*Backspace,*Delete,*End,*Home,*Right,*Left,*PgUp,*PgDn ; ...
        Loop,Parse,keys, `,
            Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, Label, On
        
        Tooltip, Active
        Sleep 2000
        Tooltip
        
        While WinActive("ahk_id" thisID) ; wait for user to navigate away
            Sleep 200
        
        Loop,Parse,keys, `,
            Hotkey, %A_LoopField%, Label, Off
        
        ; delay is just for visibility, remove tooltips for operation
        Tooltip, Inactive   
        Sleep 2000              
        Tooltip
        
    }
}


Label:
    key := A_ThisHotkey
    
    If (SubStr(key, 1,1)="*")
        key := SubStr(key, 2) ; get rid of "*" if present
    
    If (StrLen(key)>1)  ; encapsulate all special chars
        key:="{" SubStr(key, 1) "}"
    
    ; send raw and let keyboard modifiers that are already down modify the keys being sent
    ControlSend, OneNote::DocumentCanvas1, % key , ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
    
    ; OneNote misbehaves
    ControlSend, OneNote::DocumentCanvas1, {End}, ahk_exe ONENOTE.EXE
    
    ToolTip % A_ThisHotkey "-->" key        ; debug only
    
Return
```